# how to send information(data) from a FastAPI server(client) to another FastAPI(model)

Tags: python, post, fastapi

I am a newbie in RESTful API...

so I am trying to deploy two servers (client and model). The main idea is :

- Client uploads his images on the client server, the client server(port 8000) will make some transformations
- then I want the client server to make a post (with transformed data) to another server (also using FastAPI at port 8008).

Currently, I am strugling with the client server part, how to do a post to another server ?

```py
# Define a flask app
app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="./templates")

origins = ["*"]
methods = ["*"]
headers = ["*"]


app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware, 
    allow_origins = origins,
    allow_credentials = True,
    allow_methods = methods,
    allow_headers = headers    
)


@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def root(request: Request):
        return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
    #render_template('index.html')



#here the client will upload his image to the server
#and then encrypt it in the same button
@app.post('/encrypt', status_code=200)
async def upload_img(f: UploadFile = File(...)):

        ret = {}
        logger.debug(f)
        #base_path = "uploads"
        # filename = "predict.jpg"
        f.filename = "predict.jpg"
        base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        file_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'uploads',secure_filename(f.filename))
        os.makedirs(base_path, exist_ok=True)
        try:
            with open(file_path, "wb") as buffer:
                shutil.copyfileobj(f.file, buffer)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error: {}".format(str(e)))


        image_info = {"filename": f.filename,  "image": f}

        #preprocess image
        plain_input = load_input(f)
        #create a public context and drop sk
        ctx, sk = create_ctx()
        
        #encrypt 
        enc_input = prepare_input(ctx, plain_input)
        enc_input_serialize = enc_input.serialize()

        # la tu dois faire un post au serveur
        return  sk



class inference_param(BaseModel):
    context : bytes
    enc_input : bytes


@app.post("/data") #send data to the model server
async def send_data(data : inference_param):
    return data
```

Comment: Answers to this topic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556972/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73770074/17865804)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your endpoint is asynchronous you can use the asynchronous HTTP library like [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) or [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/) to make the request.

If you don't want your clients of the client server to wait until the image is uploaded you can also use [Background Tasks](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/).